# Regex for Validating SSN with *

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I need a regex that validates a proper SSN number displaying in Screen with mask.

However we show only last 4 digits of SSN and we mask other character with `*` symbol

User can either enter only a number at the place of `*` or they leave as it is.

***User can enter valid input or they never change***

`***-**-1234` `123-55-1234`

***User changed the displayed to Invalid SSN***

`5**-**-1234` `A**-**-1234` `AAA-5*-1234`

Need a **JavaScript Regex** code/article for this.

Comment: and what have you tried? why didn't it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(\d{3}-\d{2}|\*{3}-\*{2})-\d{4}
```

To allow:

```
***-**-1234
123-55-1234
```

And nothing else.

#### Explanation:

- `\d` mean a digit (that is, any number from 0 to 9 <sup>(unicode digits as well)</sup>);
- `\d{3}-\d{2}` means **3 digits, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 digits**;
- `\*{3}-\*{2}` means **3 chars `*`, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 chars `*`**;
- `|` is the alternation operator. It means roughly "or", like `(a|b)` means *match `a` or `b`*;
- So: `(\d{3}-\d{2}|\*{3}-\*{2})` means **(3 digits, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 digits) *OR* (3 chars `*`, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 chars `*`)**.
- Finally, the whole code `(...)-\d{4}` means the **same as explained in the previous item followed by the char `-` followed by  4 digits**.

In summary, `(\d{3}-\d{2}|\*{3}-\*{2})-\d{4}` means:

- **((3 digits, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 digits) *OR* (3 chars `*`, followed by the char `-` followed by 2 chars `*`)), all followed by the char `-` followed by  4 digits**

Comment: Also `***-55-1234` it is invalid. Either user can change all * or they leave as it is :(

Comment: Is there any way to achieve both?

Comment: Thought you wanted to match `***-55-1234`. I updated it. It won't match now.

Comment: @acdcjunior could you please elaborate on the code.. i am new to regex

Comment: @SamprityKashyap Yes. I edited the answer, please check and let me know if it is clear enough.